# How to render html tag inside blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to render html tags inside blade. It was so easy in plain PHP but I am confused in Laravel.

Delete Order by client:

```
{{strtoupper($name) . ' with email &lt;strong&gt;' . $email . '&lt;/strong&gt;'}}
```

I want the output to be something like this:

> *Delete Order by client: CLIENT NAME with email **example@example.com***

How can I achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: `{{strtoupper($name)}}` with email <strong>`{{ $email }}`</strong>

Comment: thanks i was confused since i am new to laravel

Comment: No need to be confused, there's [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)

Answer (score 4):

You should do your variables separate from your HTML.

```
{{ strtoupper($name) }} with email <strong>{{ $email }}</strong>
```

It's should almost never be necessary to do string concatenation the way you did inside HTML, it makes more sense to keep everything separate when you can.

This generally goes for if you are using plain PHP as well, it's usually better to echo the variables outside of HTML.

```
<div>
    <?php echo strtoupper($name); ?> with email <strong><?php echo $email; ?></strong>
</div>
```

or with short syntax

```
<div>
    <?=strtoupper($name);?> with email <strong><?=$email;?></strong>
</div>
```

because it allows you to have HTML syntax highlighting, and it looks cleaner.